# 7zip extractor flooded my home folder, any way to undo it?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, home-directory, 7zip

I recently installed 7zip on my PC to extract some .7z files I had in my Download Folder. However, when I entered:

```
7z e 'File location here'
```

The terminal result:

- 
- :
- :

All the 1700 files were extracted successfully, but also went to the /home folder flooding it.

[image]

I desperately start deleting some of the files and folders, but it's imposible to manually remove all of them.

Also tried sorting by date, but the files have [dates from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqMm7.png) 2014 to 2020 inherited by the original .7z file.

**Is there a method to undo what I did without damaging any of the files I already had before the extraction?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the list of extracted files, then script a deletion work.

List files in archive

```
7z l archive_file.ext
# l  is for 'List'
```

The output of this command looks like the code bellow:
We want the list of files with path

```
user@host:~$ 7z l '$User/RC_Adapter_Arduino.zip' 

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 560  @ 2.67GHz (20655),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 8693524 bytes (8490 KiB)          

Listing archive: /home/MyUser/RC_Adapter_Arduino.zip

--
Path = /home/MyUser/RC_Adapter_Arduino.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 8693524

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2019-09-06 08:58:18 D....            0            0  Drivers - Arduino
2019-09-06 09:06:16 D....            0            0  Drivers - Arduino/drivers
2019-09-06 09:07:30 .....         9368         6268  Drivers - Arduino/drivers/AdafruitCircuitPlayground.cat
2019-09-06 09:07:30 .....         3719         1162  Drivers - Arduino/drivers/AdafruitCircuitPlayground.inf
2019-09-06 09:06:46 D....            0            0  Drivers - Arduino/drivers/CP210x_6.7
2019-09-06 09:06:24 D....            0            0  Drivers - Arduino/drivers/CP210x_6.7.4
```

Get the last column by deleting the 53 first characters, adapt it to your output if needed
This could also be achieved with awk and dealing with spaces

```
7z l myarchive.file | sed  's/\(.\{53\}\)//'
```

Optionnal removing heading and tailing lines

```
7z l myarchive.file tail -n +17 | head -n -2 | sed  's/\(.\{53\}\)//'
```

Save the files list to a text file
You will be able to script the deletion of the unwanted files
Adapt 17 heading and 2 tailing values to your output if needed

```
7z l myarchive.file tail -n +17 | head -n -2 | sed  's/\(.\{53\}\)//' > $USER/theMess.txt
```